# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use a master page and in the header, there is a number of unread messages
master page code:

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="{{url('chat-room')}}" target="_blank" role="button">
        <span class="adminpro-icon adminpro-chat-pro"></span>
        <span class="indicator-ms"> 
            @php $totlUnread = 0; @endphp
            @foreach($chatusers as $chatuser)                                  
                @if($chatuser->unread)
                    @php $totlUnread+=$chatuser->unread; @endphp
                @endif
            @endforeach

            @if($totlUnread == 0)
                @php echo "<span class='pending'></span>"; @endphp
            @else
                @php echo "<span class='pending'>$totlUnread</span>"; @endphp
            @endif
        </span>
    </a>                          
</li>
```

when I need to pass this value (users) to all views, I Create View Composer and pass data through it.

```
public function boot()
{
    $chatusers = DB::select("select users.id, users.name, users.email, count(is_read) as unread 
    from users LEFT  JOIN  messagesnews ON users.id = messagesnews.from and is_read = 0 and messagesnews.to = " . Auth::id() . " where users.id != " . Auth::id() . " 
    group by users.id, users.name, users.email");
    View::share('chatusers', $chatusers);
}
```

but give me an error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where users.id != group by users.id, users.name, users.email' at line 3 (SQL: select users.id, users.name, users.email, count(is_read) as unread from users LEFT JOIN messagesnews ON users.id = messagesnews.from and is_read = 0 and messagesnews.to = where users.id != group by users.id, users.name, users.email)

when I use the SQL query in any controller it's working very well, but in View Composer give me an error.

Comment: Your  `Auth::id()`  is empty.

Comment: It seems that you don't have any logged in user... The error shows `users.id != group by users.id`, that means that `Auth::id()` is not returning any value

Comment: I'm logged in, But this error shows in all views

Comment: Make your life easier by setting up models and relationships.

Comment: @Script47 yes I want to make it easy, how to pass this value to multiple views?

Comment: Well, you need to figure out why `Auth::id()` does not return any value.

Comment: @Shadow you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all, I do the below and it's working well

```
 public function boot()
{
     view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $id=Auth::user()->id;
            $chatusers = DB::select("select users.id, users.name, users.email, count(is_read) as unread 
        from users LEFT  JOIN  messagesnews ON users.id = messagesnews.from and is_read = 0 and messagesnews.to = " . $id . "
       where users.id != " . $id . " 
        group by users.id, users.name, users.email");

            $view->with('chatusers', $chatusers );
            $view->with('id', $id );
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Auth::id()` will result in a null value. You should use either `Auth::user()->id` or `auth()->user()->id` to get the authenticated user's ID.

Comment: ...and using `Auth::user()->id` if the user isn't signed in would result in an error: `Cannot read property of non object [...]`

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: @HimaHima your problem is on `boot`, you don't have any users logged in that's why. What are you trying to do by the way???

Comment: I'm already logged in, I want to pass this value (chatusers) to multiple views

Comment: @HimaHima then you should just make a custom helper and call it on the boot function so that it will return a user instead of doing it the most frankenstein way possible.

Comment: because I use master page, in home page this query working well, in the inside pages I need to pass this value in every controller

Comment: It's a logic problem instead of a Laravel problem really. Voting down this post.

Comment: @rkg how can I make a custom helper and call it on the boot function? I don't know